# Axios cancel Request shows browser alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, axios, fetch

Axios cancel Request shows browser alert which stops the execution until you click ok.
I want to cancel my requests, all my Api calls are in separate file named **apiCalls.js**.

Component with cancelToken.

```
componentDidMount() {
        const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
        // create the source
        this.source = CancelToken;
    }

    persistCancel = (cancel) => {
        this.setState({cancels: [...this.state.cancels, cancel]})
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.state.cancels.forEach((c) => c());
    }
```

this is my Api call from component.

```
getScoreCardCall({profileId, campaignIds, startDate, endDate}, (scoreCards) => {
            //success
            this.setState({
                scoreCards,
                showComcardsLoader: false
            })
        },this.source,this.persistCancel);
```

and in the **apiCalls.js**

```
export function getScoreCardCall(params,callback, source,onRequest){
    axios.get(url,
        {
        cancelToken: new source(function executor(c) {
            onRequest(c);
            }),
        params:{
            profileId: params.profileId,
            campaignId: params.campaignIds.toString(),
            startDate: params.startDate,
            endDate: params.endDate,
        }
        })
    .then(res => {
        if(callback != null){
            if(res.data.length!=0){
                callback(res.data);
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
            console.log(err.message);
          }
    })
}
```

[image: alert]

Can someone please tell me why is alert showing with every request cancellation?? or what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[axios#cancellation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation)describes two ways to use the cancelToken. You used the first way, with source.token/source.cancel. I started out that way, and had a similar problem as yours: Once a request to a particular URL was canceled, I could never get a successful response from that URL again. I switched to the second method using an executor function and the problem went away. I guess was sharing the same cancelToken for multiple requests, which is what they say you can do with the executor function method. Anyway, maybe that would work for you too.